# Meaning of "hot saves" - firefighter jargon?

Tags: meaning

TV Show
Friends – the United States, sitcom. (Season 3 Episode 23)

==============

[Scene: Central Perk, Chandler, Joey, and Rachel are there, as Phoebe enters with her date.]

Phoebe: (to her date) Okay, and then this is the coffee house.

Phoebe: Vince is a fireman.

Rachel: Wow! Have you ever rescued anyone from a burning building before?

Vince: **98 hot saves**, highest in the force.

==============

What did he mean by "hot saves"? a save from "hot" places, or a "hot = exciting" save? Or something else maybe? And is "Hot save" a firemen terminology in real life in the USA?

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with IKEA?

Comment: Aside from Ricky's excellent find of an instance from 2009 (which figures in several online stories about the same heroic rescue), I found only one occurrence of "hot save[s]" in the relevant sense—from a [skeptics forum](http://www.internationalskeptics.com/forums/showthread.php?t=165841) in 2001. My searches included the words _fire_ and _rescue_ to help winnow out false-positive matches, so I may have excluded some true positives for "hot save[s]" as well, but the total number of instances is still probably quite small. My conclusion: The term "hot save[s]" is not widely known or used.

Comment: ... There is, however, an unrelated sense of the term in computer programming, according to [this source](https://books.google.com/books?id=pYFGAAAAYAAJ&q=%22hot+save%22&dq=%22hot+save%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiboufE26nJAhVB-mMKHU_eB7o4MhDoAQg2MAU) from 2004: "The term hot save refers to storing data to the stack and reading it back as a result of using a high number of registers." Otherwise, Google Books searches yield no meaningful matches for "hot save" or "hot saves."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"On the force," not "in the force."

A hot save is saving someone's life by pulling them from the fire. Yes, it's common among firemen in the U.S.

For instance:

http://prev.dailyherald.com/story/?id=264709